# List currently logged in users (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to display a list of currently logged in users?

Ideally it would just show their name and gravatar.

Comment: there is plugin, though i haven't tried it. you can get idea from this. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/

Answer (score 10):

Personaly I would use the session_tokens meta key to determine if a user is online (or has a running session) or not.

```
$aUsers = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'session_tokens',
    'meta_compare' => 'EXISTS'
]);
```

You'll get a list of Users with running sessions. Then you can use that for your output.

```
echo sprintf(
    'Users online: %s',
    implode(', ', array_map(function($oUser){
        return get_avatar( $oUser->ID, 96 ) . '<span class="username">'$oUser->display_name.'</span>';
    }, $aUsers))
);
```

You could even display the session ip addresses if you modify the last bit of code.

```
echo sprintf(
    'Users online: %s',
    implode(', ', array_map(function($oUser){
        $aCurrentSessions = get_user_meta($oUser->ID, 'session_tokens', true);
        return get_avatar( $oUser->ID, 96 ) . '<span class="username">'$oUser->display_name.'</span> (' .
            implode('; ', array_map(function($aSession) {
                return $aSession['ip']; // only return the session ips
            }, $aCurrentSessions)) . ')';
    }, $aUsers))
);
```

Comment: The first line returns even logged out users, so I suppose what you suggest is not enough

Comment: @Jozze, thanks for you answer. Would you care pointing out (to a veteran programmer but a WP beginner) how to apply this solution (e.g. into a plugin)?
If possible, a sample (PHP) file would be of much help (git/mail/other).

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress does not have a built in function for this, but you can easily add one yourself.  For example, you can use the wp_login hook to store each users last login time.  Then you can list the users that logged in within the last 30 minutes or so as online.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'store_last_login', 10, 2);

function store_last_login($current_user) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user = $current_user->user_login;
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql', 1));
}
```

Then, you can echo out the users that logged in within the last twenty minutes ( or whatever timeframe you choose) with something like:

```
function list_online_users() {
$users = get_users( 'blog_id=1' );
foreach ($users as $online) {

    $getLastLogin = (get_user_meta($online->ID, 'last_login', true));
    $lastLogin = new DateTime($getLastLogin);
    $since_start = $lastLogin->diff(new DateTime(current_time('mysql', 1)));

    $minutesSinceLogin = $since_start->i;

    // this will list every user and whether they logged in within the last 30 minutes
    if ($minutesSinceLogin > 30 ) {
        echo '<li>'.$online->user_login . ' is offline </li>';
    } else { 
        echo '<li>'.$online->user_login . ' is online </li>'; 
    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a plugin, this can be done easily :

1/ Add this to your functions.php file to add or remove a usermeta when the user connects or disconnects :

```
    function add_user_logged_meta(){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'asdb-loggedin', true);
    }
    // user connects
    add_action('init','add_user_logged_meta');

    function delete_user_logged_meta() {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'asdb-loggedin', false);
    }
    // user disconnects
    add_action('clear_auth_cookie', 'delete_user_logged_meta');
```

2/ In your templates (you could also make a function in functions.php), to show all users that are loggedin, just use the built in wordpress get_users() with some meta query params :

```
$loggedin_users = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'asdb-loggedin',
    'meta_value' => '1',
    'meta_compare' => '='
]);
foreach( $loggedin_users as $loggedin_user ){
    echo $loggedin_user->user_login;

}
```

Comment: `wp_logout` returns null. Its best to replace with 'clear_auth_cookie' . That makes this code work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for feedback ! I made the modification

Comment: Extremely useful, I'm going to try and produce a column on the Users admin page

Answer (score 0):

A solution which can be run from the cli:

```
$ cat > active_users.php
<?php
$users = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'session_tokens',
    'meta_compare' => 'EXISTS'
]);

echo sprintf(
    "%-20s %-17s %s\n",
    "User login",
    "IP",
    "Login time"
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $sessions = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'session_tokens', true);
    foreach ($sessions as $ses) {
        if ($ses['expiration']>time()) {
            echo sprintf(
                "%-20s %-17s %s\n",
                $user->user_login,
                $ses['ip'],
                date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ses['login'])
            );
        }
    }
}

^C
$ wp eval-file active_users.php 
User login           IP                Login time
chris                132.190.34.233    2024-02-06 13:23:01
```

Answer (score -1):

1)Create on extra field named as 'status' with enum('1','0') in wp_users table
2)after in functions.php put following code

```
<?php
function add_session_mitesh()
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_users SET `status` = '1' WHERE `wp_users`.`ID` = $user_id;");
    }
     $user_id;
}
add_action('init','add_session_mitesh');


function delete_session_mitesh() {
global $wpdb;
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_users SET `status` = '0' WHERE `wp_users`.`ID` = $user_id;");
    }
 $user_id;
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'delete_session_mitesh');
?>
```

now to list the currently login user you can use

```
<?php  $users=$wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_users where status='1'', 'ARRAY_A'); 
<table width="100%" border="2px" style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
    foreach( $users as $g )
    {   
    ?>
        <tr><td style="text-align: center;"> <center> <?php echo $g['user_login'] ?> </center></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </p>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please don’t do this. Hacking WordPress core is a terrible idea - and that’s exactly what creating an extra column in a WordPress core table is doing. These days, WordPress stores tokens and you can find those in other answers here.

Answer (score -4):

You can get current logged in user in following way

> ```
> $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
> echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
> echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
> echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
> echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
> echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
> echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />'; ?>
> ```

id this $current_user variable you can find all the user details in array and object you can take from this variable

Comment: He did not ask for a single user's info; he asked for a list of all logged in users at the moment.